# Cant understand why RepositoryRestController does not work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I use Spring Data Rest and I can not understand why my RepositoryRestController does not work. Its code:

```
  @RepositoryRestController
  public class Cntrl {
  @Autowired
  private UserDao userDao;


  @RequestMapping(name = "/users/{id}/nameOne",method = 
  RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public PersistentEntityResource setNameOne(@PathVariable("id") Long id, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler){
User user = userDao.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->{
throw new ServerException("Wrong id");
});

user.setLogin("One");
userDao.save(user);
return persistentEntityResourceAssembler.toFullResource(user);
 }
 }
```

And Spring Boot start  class:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableScheduling
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
    public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    }
```

When i go to base path (localhost:8080/api) everything is fine, but when  send GET to request to  localhost:8080/api/users/1/nameOne I get empty response, i dont have other controllers and I have user with id 1, so why it is not working ?

Comment: Any informations in the server logfiles?

Comment: nothing, server doesn't react to the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the URL structure you are using has already a meaning in Spring Data Rest context.

`/{repository}/{id}/{column}` URL is handled at `RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference` method.

`/api/users/1/nameOne` means: get the `nameOne` column of the user with the id of 1. An important note is that: this column should reference another `@Entity`. This means if you have a `String` column named "surname" and you hit the URL `/api/users/1/name` you will get 404 because this column is not referencing another entity. If you have a column named school which references to a `School` entity and you hit the URL `/api/users/1/school` you will get the referenced school entity for that user. If the user does not have a school then you will get 404 again.

Also, `@RepositoryRestController` can be used for `@RequestMapping` if the URL you are giving isn't colliding with Spring Data Rest.

You can test that with the following example:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class CustomRepositoryRestController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/repositoryRestControllerTest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String nameOne() {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

Visit http://localhost:8080/repositoryRestControllerTest

I hope this explanation clarifies things for you.

Comment: Ye, you are right! I understood it few days ago, but forgot to write answer to this question! Anyway, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If `localhost:8080/api` is your root context, then `localhost:8080/api/users/1/nameOne` should be the url you are using for the user GET.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could figure out, if you use a `RepositoryRestController` you **must** activate the path using a corresponding `RestRepositoryResource`, before it's available in a controller, i.e. this would work:

```
// new code
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/users")
public interface UserDaoRepository extends Repository<UserDao, String> {}

// your code
@RepositoryRestController
public class Cntrl {
  @Autowired
  private UserDao userDao;


  @RequestMapping(name = "/users/{id}/nameOne",method = 
  RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public PersistentEntityResource setNameOne(@PathVariable("id") Long id, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler){
      User user = userDao.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->{
      throw new ServerException("Wrong id");
    });

    user.setLogin("One");
    userDao.save(user);
    return persistentEntityResourceAssembler.toFullResource(user);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could opt to use a `BasePathAwareController` instead of `RepositoryRestController`, which does not require a resource.

```
@BasePathAwareController  // <<<< NOT @RepositoryRestController
public class Cntrl {
  @Autowired
  private UserDao userDao;

  @RequestMapping(name = "/users/{id}/nameOne",method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public PersistentEntityResource setNameOne(@PathVariable("id") Long id, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler){
      User user = userDao.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->{
      throw new ServerException("Wrong id");
    });

    user.setLogin("One");
    userDao.save(user);
    return persistentEntityResourceAssembler.toFullResource(user);
  }
}
```